# how to debug the coredump file produced by spawn-fcgi?

Tags: c++, nginx, gdb, coredump, spawn-fcgi

my **coredump** file is produced by the shell command `sudo spawn-fcgi fcgi-bin -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8089 &`, `fcgi-bin` is compiled by the c++ command `g++ -g fcgiMain.cpp fcgiEnv.cpp -o fcgi-bin` etc. to deploy with nginx ,as we know that debug coredump file with the command `gdb ./test_bin test_coredump`,but now i have two bin program `spawn-fcgi` and "fcgi-bin",if i use the command `gdb ./spawn-fcgi coredump` and `bt` to look at the stack ,then it will look like this picture

[image]

so anybody can tell me how to deal with this **coredump** file ,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate executables at play here: `spawn-fcgi` and `fcgi-bin`. The former `exec`s the latter.

In the GDB output, you can see that the `core` was produced by `fcgi-bin`. Therefore, that's the executable you want to give to GDB:

```
gdb fcgi-bin coredump
```